# Zeroth order method with near-optimal rate that works in practice?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find a ZO (zeroth-order, i.e. no access to gradient) algorithm to minimize a strongly-convex deterministic objective (say, as a sum of smooth and nonsmooth proximable functions). I want such algorithm to have at most $O(n)$ worse theoretical convergence rate than the optimal first-order algorithm which has $O(\sqrt{\frac{L}{\mu}} \log\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ rate, where $n$ is variable dimension, and $L$, $\mu$ are smoothness and strongly-convex constants. I also want this algorithm to work well in practice.

In this paper [Random gradient-free minimization of convex functions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10208-015-9296-2), Nesterov and Spokoiny gave an algorithm (see algorithm and theorem 9 in: section 6, accelerated random search) that has $O(n\sqrt{\frac{L}{\mu}} \log\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ rate I want, but in practice, even for a toy problem, it runs notoriously slowly and never converges to the $10^{-3}$ accuracy I want. I tried many other ZO methods, they all have very slow practical convergence.

Does anyone know any ZO method (for strongly-convex minimization) that actually works in practice? Please let me know, thank you so much  : )